# Laravel 5 : Customize HTML Form validation in controller file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using following code in controller file. I have an element name `title` in view form. Following code is showing correct validation. But, i need to **customize** this error.

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|max:255',
  ]);

if ($v->fails())
{
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass as third argument of `Validator` your custom messages.

```
$messages = [
    'title.required' => 'You need to insert a pretty title'
];
v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'title' => 'required|max:255',
  ], $messages
);
```